# GDAL MVT Multithreading

Tags: gdal, vector-tiles

I am trying to speed up my MVT generation with GDAL. The GDAL documentation says that some of the work can be multi-threaded by use of the `GDAL_NUM_THREADS` parameter. From my understanding by default there should be as many threads in the pool as many cores there are on the machine. Since I run on Azure VM, I tried scaling up and down between 4 and 16 core but my MVT test data always processes in 10minutes, regardless of the VM spec. I tried running ogr2ogr both with setting `--config GDAL_NUM_THREADS 2` (to try force slow down) or help speed up with `--config GDAL_NUM_THREADS 12` by hinting to use more threads. Still I my processing time is nearly fixed and does not change. I also tried setting the environmental variable `GDAL_NUM_THREADS 12` but no change with performance. Does anyone know please how well the GDAL MVT actually multi-threads? Can this help speed things up in any significant way? Or is there a different way to control the multi-threading ?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this from gdal-dev mailing list. GDAL developers tend to be rather responsive. But multithreading is probably used more often with the raster side of GDAL where processed like warping etc. may be relatively easy to do in parallel processes. When it comes to MVT, if the tiles are written into MBTiles that is a SQLite database and allows only one database connection at a time to do writing, then it could be that multithreading would not make the process any faster.

Comment: Thank you, I will ask on the mailing list

Comment: This is of general interest, so it would be useful to share your findings here, once you have something. Very likely, you are using `ogr2ogr`, and/or `fiona`, and/or `rtree`. So,  `--config GDAL_NUM_THREADS 12` will have no effect on the processing time. Also, @user30184 's comment on DB connectivity sounds like another bottleneck. I have had some huge shapefiles (>10 GB) that took me over 24hrs in Windows 32GB RAM machine to create MVT but smaller files are rather fast. What's your input file format/size like?

Comment: So far I have no findings yet. In my process I also try to run lots (50-100) of concurrently running ogr2ogr.exe processes on one machine, and what I found was that the Antivirus software had big impact on performance, so setting some exceptions has helped.